# Printing on pre-printed awards certificates to complete information

Tags: print-design

I have multiple 8.5 x 11 card stock winner/participation certificates.  They have a certain layout and design with a few blanks to fill out specific information.  I do not currently have a soft copy of the template, I was only given the actual stock copies, but then again I probably would not wish to go reprint on new stock.  I wish to at least fill in the few blanks but perhaps also create a custom image/logo in a blank area of the award if it is not too hard.

What is the best way to accomplish this?  I am worried about the printers available to me and working with card stock.  Also, I don't have professional graphics packages available to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you require is not particularly difficult with the correct approach.

Consider to use your preferred word processor to create the fields to match the certificate. Create text boxes and image/graphic boxes in approximate locations on the document.

Print test text and images on ordinary paper, thinner is better. Hold the certificate and test print together to a strong light, to determine alignment adjustments needed.

Once you have the boxes placed as needed and sized to your requirements, turn off the borders of the boxes and print with confidence.

Comment: Actually, it turns out that my stock is thin enough such that replacing the test prints with holding my stock against the monitor when my word processor is open helps me to get locations correct.  So everything is where it should be, I just have to figure out how to print out 32 quickly as each document requires a different name.

Comment: If you're familiar with mail merge and your word processor supports it, you can use merge fields in the appropriate places and create one document with a list of names which when merged with the form document will generate all 32 in a third document.  We print our christmas card envelopes each year in this manner.